# Controller in separate assembly and routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In the same solution, there is a ASP.NET MVC4 application `Slick.App` and class library `Awesome.Mvc.Lib`. Awesome.Mvc.Lib contains one controller class.

```
public class ShinnyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Hello, from Awesome.Mvc.Lib";
    }
}
```

If I just add the reference from Slick.App to Awesome.Mvc.Lib, run the application and point brower to `/shinny`, I will actually see the response "Hello, from Awesome.Mvc.Lib".

This is something I don't expect at all. All the time I thought ASP.NET MVC respects the namespaces there the controllers placed in. So, the controllers from another namespaces are not exposed, at least before I didn't ask to.

I tried to change the default route registration, to use namespaces parameter.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new [] { "Slick.App.Controllers" }
    );
```

Still, the ShinnyController route still match for '/shinny'.

I have a concerns this is right default behaviour. My question is, how to explicitly say which controllers are exposed and prevent default route to match controllers in separate class library?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The namespaces list on the route only gives ***priority*** to certain namespaces over the others, which are not listed :

```
new [] {"Namespace1", "Namespace2"}
```

doesn't give higher priority to Namespace1 as one would expect but just gives priority to both namespaces over the others.

This means that the namespaces in the list are first searched for controllers and then, if no match is found the rest of the available controllers with that name are used.

You can suppress the use of non prioritized controllers by doing this:

```
var myRoute  = routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new [] { "Slick.App.Controllers" }
    );

myRoute.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can inherit from DefaultControllerFactory like this:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override Type GetControllerType(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var type = base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);

        if (type != null && IsIngored(type))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return type;
    }

    public static bool IsIngored(Type type)
    {
        return type.Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnoreAssemblyAttribute), false).Any() 
            || type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnoreControllerAttribute), false).Any();
    }
}
```

Then some changes to Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomControllerFactory());
    }
```

And here you are! Any type marked with IgnoreControllerAttribute won't be visible. You can even hide the whole assembly.

If you need some configuration based behaviour, it is not a great matter to make all necessary changes ;)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is not exactly what's my problem is. My problem is that I don't have any access to host application, so creation of custom controller factory would not work for me.

Comment: @alexanderb: No, you can do this, using this: [assembly: System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MvcTools.Hooks.PreApplicationStartCode), "Start")], see this link: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/register-your-http-modules-at-runtime.html There in start, you do this: System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(YOUR_ControllerFactory)); All you need to do is to get the host application to load your dll, which you can achieve by a web.config entry ;)