# How can create a route to main project MVC to another project MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, maproute

I have one solution with two project MVC. I added a references to second project to main project. I create a new  MapRoute in first project to second project.

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "second",
           url: "second",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
           namespaces: new[] { @"SecondProject.Controllers" });
```

this code has been added in RouteConfig in main project

when I write in URL address https://localhost/second... not working...any idea why?

Comment: Is that route the first one (or before any other matching routes)

Comment: I think you want to know if I have implicit route or not. I'm right? @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

First up all please check the namespace path is right at your end. then add below line in route config after route declaration.

```
myRoute.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

you can refer stackoverflow link as well which may be helpful
[Controller in separate assembly and routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077554/controller-in-separate-assembly-and-routing)